# SSMS export to CSV trouble

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssms

I'm exporting data from SSMS as a CSV, I'm checking my work by downloading the data again, but the second time around (and when using different data) I'm getting the below errors in export wizard. It had been working previously, but now every time I attempt the export these errors pop up. Any ideas for fixing this?

> Error 0xc0202009: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. 
>   An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005. An OLE DB record
>   is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0" 
>   Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Protocol error in TDS stream". An
>   OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native
>   Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Protocol error in TDS
>   stream". An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server
>   Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Communication
>   link failure". An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL
>   Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "TCP
>   Provider: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote
>   host. ".  (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)   Error 0xc0047038:
>   Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The
>   PrimeOutput method on Source - Query returned error code 0xC0202009. 
>   The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called
>   PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the
>   component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing. 
>   There may be error messages posted before this with more information
>   about the failure.

(SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Comment: Sounds like SSIS has got itself blocked. Do you have sufficient access to restart the SSIS service before you try again?

Comment: No I don't believe I do. I was able to overcome this by restarting my computer and shutting down my excel application multiple times for it to end up working. Still unsure of what caused it though and wary of it happening in the future.

Comment: You didn't mention Excel before. All of the office applications, especially Word and Excel, hold "exclusive locks" on files you have open in them. Could be that you had the CSV file open in Excel at the time preventing SSIS from accessing it.

Comment: I was unaware of that. I was exporting to flat file destination and saved it as a CSV to be opened using excel. Thanks for the note.